# How to use getById? (ExtJS 4.1)

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I want to get the raw value of a numberfield by looking up its [id](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.AbstractElement-method-getById). Here the raw value is 4 and the id of the [numberfield](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Number-cfg-id) is satirSayisi.

[image: Trying to get the value of the number field from a different locition by looking up the numberfield's id]

I have tried several combinations but non has worked.

```
grid.header.getById('satirSayisi').getRawValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.getCmp('satirSayisi').getRawValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a little short on detail, but I think I've got the idea.  You have a grid, and you want to 1) get the selection, 2) get the model from this selection so that you can  3) get the value of a number field (satirSayisi).  I'm assuming satirSayisi is the column name in the model, and not necessarily the id or itemId property.

Assuming that you have a handle on the grid, you grab a model from the selection like so:

```
var model = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
```

Now you have a model instance (which should correspond to your database columns in some way).  To get the value from satirSayisi, you would say:

```
var stuff = model.get('satirSayisi');
```

Accessing components by Id in ExtJS is no longer recommended.  They suggest the use of itemId over id. A better way to get access to an object is ComponentQuery, such as...

```
component = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button#Save')[0];
```

This example will give you a handle on the first button type object in your application with the itemId of Save.  It will always grab stuff in an array, even when there is just one result.

Good luck!